# How do I make Excel return the most frequent value in one cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a single cell which contains a long list of numbers, delimited by a comma and a space.

Some of the numbers are repeated, and I want to know which number is repeated the most.

The function MODE doesn't work and seems designed to work on a range where every value is in its own cell.

Example of what I need

```
Cell with numbers
123, 456, 456

Most frequently repeated value
 456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your values are numbers like you show:

```
=MODE.SNGL(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"))
```

the `"<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>"` creates an xml string.  Then `FILTERXML(...,"//b")` returns the array of numbers.  Then `MODE.SNGL` returns the largest repeating item.

[image]

---

If text or a mix:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),MODE.SNGL(MATCH(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),0)))
```

This time we use Match to return an array of numbers(where it matches the first match, in the below case the would be `1,2,2`)  The `MODE_SNGL` then returns the `2` to the INDEX.
[image]

Comment: Nice. Now it works. Next task: go to excel jet to get my head around what I've just done!

Answer (score 1):

Try this short User Defined Function:

```
Public Function splitt(s As String) As Variant
    Dim mx As Long, i As Long, j As Long, mxkp As Long
    arr = Split(s, ", ")
    mx = 0
    mxkp = 0
    splitt = arr(0)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        v = arr(i)
        mx = 0
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
            If v = arr(j) Then mx = mx + 1
        Next j
        If mx > mxkp Then
            mxkp = mx
            splitt = v
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

[image]